# XML to HTML using XSL - check node contents

Tags: html, xml, web-services, xslt

```
<A>
  <B>Hello</B>
  <B>Goodbye</B>
  <B>Hello</B>
</A>
```

And this XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/" > 
   <html>
      <body> 
         <xsl:apply-templates/> 
      </body>
   </html>
</xsl:template>
```

I want XSL to ONLY print out something where there are B nodes containing "Hello".

NOTE: I don't want to print the actual node contents ("Hello"), I want to print something else i.e:

"Nice to meet you"
"Nice to meet you"

(As there are 2 nodes with "Hello" present and the "Goodbye is ignored")

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="B[text()='Hello']" >  
   Nice to meet you 
</xsl:template>  


<xsl:template match="/" >  
   <html> 
      <body>  
         <xsl:apply-templates/>  
      </body> 
   </html> 
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a variation to Eric's, this should also work. Eric's is more generic as you can write a template per node-type without having to change the root template. However if there isn't a matching template, the default template gets applied (which probably means the 'Goobye' node will print out 'Goodbye'). On the other hand, the solution below will only call apply-templates for the nodes where 'B' contains Hello, so the 'Goodbye' node is ignored (or it should do; it's untested, but the principle should be sound :-) ).

```
<xsl:template match="node()" >
   Nice to meet you 
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="/" >  
   <html> 
      <body>  
         <xsl:apply-templates select="/A/B[text()='Hello']" />  
      </body> 
   </html> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I've just fixed-up the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You need three rules:

```
<xsl:template match="/" >
    <html>
       <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="B[contains(.,'HELLO')]">
    <xsl:text>Nice to meet you</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

**Note**: First your own rule, second the rule for `B` element containing 'HELLO' in its string value (concatenation of all descendant text nodes), third overwriting built-in text nodes rule (output string value) with an empty rule (no output).